# Unable to run any Meteor Js command

Tags: meteor, command-line, installation

What's the cause of this problem and how do I fix it?

```
Machine:~ username$ meteor create project
'/Users/username/.meteor' exists, but '/Users/username/.meteor/meteor' is not executable.

Remove it and try again.
Machine:~ username$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m unable to tell what the problem is, but you can likely fix it by moving the file and installing meteor again. To move the file:

`$ mv ~/.meteor/meteor ~/meteor.bak`

Then try to reinstall meteor.

[EDIT]
You can additionally try to `chmod +x ~/.meteor/meteor` but the meteor instructions recommend removing the file so I recommend you move it and rename just as a back up until you reinstall.